# ASP MVC dot net Core sent object from view to controller doesnt contains all data

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've created a simple view containing a table with rows that represents entities and have possibility to modify some elements of data.

```
@model List<Models.DTO.DBO.ConnectorDto>
    
            @foreach (var entity in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <form asp-controller="Connectors" asp-action="Modify">
                        <th>
                            <input type="text" readonly name="Id" value="@entity.Id"/>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => entity.EntityFromType, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumerators.ObjectType)).Cast<Enumerators.ObjectType>().Select(enumValue => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = enumValue.ToString(),
                                Value = ((int)enumValue).ToString(),
                                Selected = entity.EntityFromType == enumValue
                            }), new { @name = "EntityFromType" })
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="text" name="EntityFromId" value="@entity.EntityFromId" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => entity.EntityToType, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumerators.ObjectType)).Cast<Enumerators.ObjectType>().Select(enumValue => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = enumValue.ToString(),
                                Value = ((int)enumValue).ToString(),
                                Selected = entity.EntityToType == enumValue
                            }), new { @name = "EntityToType" })
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="text" name="EntityToId" value="@entity.EntityToId" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="datetime" readonly name="CreatedAt" value="@entity.CreatedAt" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="datetime" readonly name="LastUpdatedAt" value="@entity.LastUpdatedAt" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input name="{@entity.Id}submit" type="submit" value="Zmodyfikuj" />
                        </th>
                    </form>
                    <th>
                        <form asp-controller="Connectors" asp-action="Remove">
                            <input name="{@entity.Id}remove" type="submit" value="Usuń" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="entityId" value="@entity.Id" />
                        </form>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            }
```

this is my model structure:

```
       public class ConnectorDto : GamingBase
    {
        public Enumerators.ObjectType EntityFromType { get; set; } = Enumerators.ObjectType.Unknown;
        public Enumerators.ObjectType EntityToType { get; set; } = Enumerators.ObjectType.Unknown;

        public int EntityFromId { get; set; } = 0;
        public int EntityToId { get; set; } = 0;

        public Enumerators.ObjectType OldEntityFromType { get; set; } = Enumerators.ObjectType.Unknown;
        public Enumerators.ObjectType OldEntityToType { get; set; } = Enumerators.ObjectType.Unknown;

        public int OldEntityFromId { get; set; } = 0;
        public int OldEntityToId { get; set; } = 0;
    } 
public abstract class GamingBase : Base
{
    public string? DeveloperName { get; set; }
    public string? DeveloperDescription { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }
} 
public abstract class Base
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public Enumerators.ObjectType ObjectType { get; set; }
}  

    public enum ObjectType
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Action = 1,
        Dialogue = 2,
        Conversation = 3,
        Hero = 4,
        User = 5,
        Connector = 6,
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public class ConnectorsController : BaseController<ConnectorDto>
    {
        public ConnectorsController(AppDbContext appDbContext, ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment) : base(appDbContext, logger, hostingEnvironment)
        {
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = ConnectorService.GetDto();
            

            return View("Index", result);
        }

        public IActionResult Error(string errorMessage)
        {
            return View(errorMessage);
        }

        [HttpPost("Modify")]
        public IActionResult Modify(ConnectorDto entity)
        {
            return ConnectorService.Update(entity) ? Index() : Error("some silly message for you now");
        }

        [HttpPost("Remove")]
        public IActionResult Remove(int entityId)
        {
            return ConnectorService.Delete(ConnectorService.GetDbo(entityId)) ? Index() : Error("dupa chłopie");
        }

        [HttpPost("Create")]
        public IActionResult Create(ConnectorDto entity)
        {
            return ConnectorService.Add(entity) ? Index() : Error("dupa chłopie");
        }
    }
```

problem i've is that whenever im sending object from view to model i'm getting this:

```
entity
{Models.DTO.DBO.ConnectorDto}
    CreatedAt: {10.07.2023 10:34:24}
    Description: null
    DeveloperDescription: null
    DeveloperName: null
    EntityFromId: 0
    EntityFromType: Action
    EntityToId: 0
    EntityToType: Action
    Id: 0
    LastUpdatedAt: {01.01.0001 00:00:00}
    Name: null
    ObjectType: Unknown
    OldEntityFromId: 0
    OldEntityFromType: Unknown
    OldEntityToId: 0
    OldEntityToType: Unknown
```

as You can see, `EntityFromId: 0`, `EntityToId: 0`, `Id: 0`,`CreatedAt:`, `LastUpdatedAt:` are default

below is payload from browser

```
Id: 3
entity.EntityFromType: 1
EntityFromId: 123
entity.EntityToType: 1
EntityToId: 123
CreatedAt: 09.07.2023+17%3A12%3A20
LastUpdatedAt: 09.07.2023+17%3A12%3A20
%7B3%7Dsubmit: Zmodyfikuj
```

and begore abyone would ask, in controller metod i've already try `[FromFrom]` and setting `[HttpPost('Modify')]`. without any expected outcome...

Comment: In your controller you have two method?  Modify and  HttpPost Modify ?  What's your @entity in your form? How you define it ?

Comment: @QingGuo i've updated code listing

Comment: Your model structure don't have CreatedAt, could you share the full  ConnectorDto?

Comment: @QingGuo listing updated :) with full inheritance for ConnectorDTO model

Comment: I test your code and I can get the Id. like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUF26.gif

Comment: @QingGuo ok. thanks for validation. i have one more option in my pocket. delete all builds, dependencies, and .vs folder